# Measuring speed of a vehicle

Tags: soft-question, acoustics, measurements

I'm very primitive with my thought. So please help if you can in layman terms with an answer to this question.
Here we go-  by using a street power pole as the source responder, is it possible to read a speed of a traveling car by using two reflectors on the road which sonar back to the source? My thought is reflector A and B placed at a calculated distance apart on the road, and the source (positioned on the power pole) is measuring the  continuous flow of sonar between both. 
A car travels over reflector 'A' disturbing the sonar flow as it continues it then travels over reflector 'B'. The source reads the speed between both reflectors.

Comment: Hi Leanne, it's not really obvious what the picture is. Can you add a link to an image, so someone can attach it to the main question? Later as you gain a little more reputation, you will be able to do that yourself.

Comment: If you place the sonar transmitter on the pole, the sound will reflect back from the car, and the reflection will be Doppler-shifted so you can tell the speed from that. This is the same principle as a radar speed gun.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about your problem, you want to find the time taken between the disturbance created in the both sonar beams (Much like a tripwire, right, just using sound).
Then you want to use $v=\frac st$ to calculate the speed of the car.

There will be some technical problems with this.

- First of all, you'll have to keep the reflectors close enough. Using the formula above, you only get the *average speed* of the car. So the best approximation for the *actual speed* will be given by the *average speed* when $s$ is pretty small. The problem this can cause is that the sonar *beams* can intersect and mix up if you keep the reflectors too close. You can obtain higher precision with lasers(and the reflectors will be a lot cheaper and smaller too).
- There's no guarantee you will detect the exact moment the car crosses the beam. The sonar waves could reflect off the car and reach back to the source, never triggering the source that the car crosses. Some smart people could use retro-reflectors to *trick* the source into never detecting the car. Same problem with lasers.

The solution

> You could use the principle of the [Doppler Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect), as pointed out by @hdhondt in the comments, which is also used by the [Radar Gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_gun).
>
> The Doppler Effect states that the wavelength of waves generated by a source or received by a receiver change according to the velocity of the source and receiver.

I'm skipping the derivation of this result here. Maybe you can figure it out yourself!

So the frequency of sonar received by the receiver will be equal to
$$f_{received}=\frac{v_s+v_{car}}{v_s-v_{car}} f_{transmitted}$$

You know $f_{transmitted}$ as you'll be setting it in the source, and you also know $v_s$ which is the speed of sound in *still* air. $f_{received}$ can be measured be the receiver and all that's left is simple calculation.

Note that $v_s$ is the speed of sound in ***still*** air. If there's wind this quantity will change. That's why using light instead of sound is better because speed of light is always constant.

Answer (score 1):

> **is it possible to read a speed of a traveling car by using two reflectors on the road**

Yes it's possible but there will be many practical difficulties.

In practice, in my part of the world, when the road-traffic authorities want to measure speed of vehicles at a fixed point in a road they typically use one of two methods:

- They place two rubber tubes across the road, these are pressurised and when a vehicle's wheels travel over the tubes, a pressure sensor registers the change in pressure this causes. As the same wheel travels over the second tube the second sensor registers this in the same way, by knowing the distance between tubes and the measuring the difference in time you can calculate speed. This is in some ways similar to your idea. Rubber tubes have some obvious advantages for use over a period of a few days or weeks only.
- They use a radar gun that measures doppler shift. This works better for ad-hoc use (a policeman checking vehicle speeds for an hour or so) or for permanent use (part of a permanent speed-camera installation)

Possible advantages of a rubber tube pair over a road-surface mounted reflector pair:

- not affected by dirt, oil, debris, rain etc
- not affected by curvature of road surface (for shedding water)
- doesn't require orientation of a reflecting surface
- alignment is much less complex
- not triggered by birds, dogs etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, though a bit tricky

The first reflector, $A$ is a distance $d$ from the pole;  the second reflector, $B$, is a distance $D$ further along from $A$.  $(D<d)$.  The car's speed is $V$, and the speed of sound is $S$ .   $(V<S)$

Assume that the car passes A at time $T=0$.  This causes a disturbance to propagate through the air at a velocity S, reaching the detector a distance $d$ away at $T_1=\frac{d}{S}$

The car proceeds on, reaching $B$ at a time $T=\frac{D}{V}$.  This generated a second disturbance that also travels to the detector.  It travels a distance $d-D$ at velocity S, reaching the detector at a time $T_2$;$$T_2=\frac{D}{V}+\frac{d-D}{S}$$

Thus, at the detector:$$T_2-T_1=\frac{D}{V}+\frac{d-D}{S}-\frac{d}{S}$$Re-arranging, and noting that $\frac{d}{S}$ cancels out:$$\frac{T_2-T_1}{D}=\frac{1}{V}-\frac{1}{S}$$So, take the time difference, divide by the reflector separation, add $\frac{1}{S}$, and flip the answer...